# Why does sklearn refer to PCA loadings as components?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

Maybe this is a simple confusion on terminology but I think of **PCA Components** as the *reduced* matrix with each component being orthogonal. With `sklearn`, this is done like so,

```
reduced_data = pd.DataFrame(pca.transform(df_scaled))
```

I think of *PCA Loadings* as the weights assigned to the original variables. Confusingly, these are extracted from the fitted PCA model using

```
factor_loadings = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_)
```

Is my terminology wrong, or are these terms used interchangeably?

Comment: in the study of factor analysis we call them factor loadings, in the PCA study we call them components. ie the name is in the title PRINCIPAL COMPONENT ANALYSIS. One is in FA the other is in PCA. try not to mix the terminologies. They might seem similar bet there is a difference, though both are computed via eigen decomposition